# Ruby on Rails, `link_to` with `image_tag` talk to a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, link-to

Hi I'm currently learning Ruby On Rails and I have a little mistake.

I want to add a hyperlink on my image and when I click on this image **I want to talk to my function 'add_to_cart'**. Right now it's currently working with **button_add** but not with the function **link_to**.

My link_to code:

```
<%= link_to image_tag(product.image_url, :alt => product.title, :width => 100, :border => 1), :id => product, :action => 'add_to_cart' %>
```

The error:

```
Unknown action

The action 'show' could not be found for StoreController
```

Hyperlink HTML:

```
<a href="/store/2">
   <img width="100" border="1" src="/assets/images/cover_test.jpg" alt="Book 2">
</a>
```

Thanks You for your help :)!

**------ SOLUTION ------**

I can't answer my question but I found the solution. I had a problem with my route.rb configuration, it's was creating a conflict with my function index.

Old route.rb config:

```
match 'store/:id', :to => 'store#add_to_cart'
```

New route.rb config:

```
match 'store/add_to_cart/:id', :to => 'store#add_to_cart'
```

Here's my link_to code:

```
<%= link_to image_tag(product.image_url, :alt => product.title, :width => 100, :border => 1), {:action => 'add_to_cart', :id => product} %>
```

Thank You @Justin for your help :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I had a problem with my route.rb configuration, it's was creating a conflicts with my function index.

Old route.rb config:

```
match 'store/:id', :to => 'store#add_to_cart'
```

New route.rb config:

```
match 'store/add_to_cart/:id', :to => 'store#add_to_cart'
```

Here's my link_to code:

```
<%= link_to image_tag(product.image_url, :alt => product.title, :width => 100, :border => 1), {:action => 'add_to_cart', :id => product} %>
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this?

```
<%= link_to image_tag(product.image_url, :alt => product.title, :width => 100, :border => 1), {:controller => 'your_controller', :action => 'add_to_cart', :id => product} %>
```

(not tested)

Comment: was id a parameter? or was it an element of the img tag?

Comment: Now it's give me this error:
No route matches {:controller=>"store_controller", :action=>"add_to_cart", :id=>#<Product id: 1, title: "Fredy Nights", description: "<p>Ce livre est vraiment très bon pour apprendre ru...", image_url: "images/cover_test.jpg", created_at: "2012-01-25 01:50:29", updated_at: "2012-02-02 01:55:48", price: #<BigDecimal:101323028,'0.1001E2',18(18)>>}

Comment: Route.rb =  match 'store/:id', :to => 'store#add_to_cart' ... Sorry for all the comment it will be easier to read :).

Answer (score 0):

```
link_to(body, url_options = {}, html_options = {})
# url_options, except :confirm or :method,
# is passed to url_for
```

the second parameters is about url options, and the third parameters is about html options

learn how to lookup api document and it will avoid this kind of mistake